# Convert time to seconds

Tags: php, time

What the best way to convert 24 hours time to seconds so it can be used for comparison if statement..

```
function HourMinuteToDecimal($hour_minute) {
        $t = explode(':', $hour_minute);
        return $t[0] * 60 + $t[1];
}

echo HourMinuteToDecimal("23:30");
return 1410
```

If you try to convert midnight time (00:00) to seconds, it will not work.  What is the solution to this?

00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, etc.

```
if (HourMinuteToDecimal("01:30") > HourMinuteToDecimal("23:30")) { .. }
```

This will not work.

Comment: when you say converting '00:00' won't work, what do you mean? It will result in zero seconds, but that's correct isn't it? If you want 00:00 to mean 24 hours rather than zero hours, then you'll need to make it a special case.

Comment: Thats true, when you say special case... like what? I have code something like this: if (HourMinuteToDecimal("01:30") > HourMinuteToDecimal("23:30")) { .. } That woudnt work as expected.. How to sove this issue?

Comment: @user622378: In order to solve the "issue", you have to state what the problem is. You said "this will not work" and "that wouldn't work as expected", but don't go on to say _why_. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Tomalak Geret'kal, I dont know hot to explain the problem. I want 00:00 to mean 24 hours. HourMinuteToDecimal function need to be updated I think to handle it but im not sure how to. HourMinuteToDecimal function only work without 12 hours time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert function:

```
function hoursToSecods ($hour) { // $hour must be a string type: "HH:mm:ss"

    $parse = array();
    if (!preg_match ('#^(?<hours>[\d]{2}):(?<mins>[\d]{2}):(?<secs>[\d]{2})$#',$hour,$parse)) {
         // Throw error, exception, etc
         throw new RuntimeException ("Hour Format not valid");
    }

         return (int) $parse['hours'] * 3600 + (int) $parse['mins'] * 60 + (int) $parse['secs'];

}
```

Write on the fly, no tested :-P

so, you can use strtotime to convert the format date in unix timestamp and comparte using a standar operators (== < > >= <= !=, etc)  ex:

```
$t1 = "23:40:12";
$t2 = "17:53:04";

$h1 = strtotime("0000-00-00 $t1");
$h2 = strtotime("0000-00-00 $t2");

$h1 == $h2; // if are equals
$h1 > $h2; // if h1 is mayor at h2
$h1-$h2; // dieference in seconds, etc.
```

etc..

Comment: $t1 = hoursToSecods("00:00:00"); would not work. 00:00:00 is mightnight 12am

Comment: yes, but if you read the question; "What the best way to convert 24 hours time to seconds so it can be used for comparison if statement..", the 00:00:00 is a 0 secods past of day.

Answer (score 10):

PHP5.3

```
$formattedTime = '00:01:38';
$seconds = strtotime('1970-01-01 ' . $formattedTime . 'GMT')
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be asking contradicting things.

- You want to convert a time in `HH:MM` into seconds.
- But then you want to "compare" the result from different times, as if they had dates attached.

If you want to allow `HourMinuteToDecimal("01:30") > HourMinuteToDecimal("23:30")` to be true without a date, then, well, any comparison will return `true`.

If you want to do this properly, include the date (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`) and use `strtotime` in PHP to get the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch.

---

Also, your function returns minutes, not seconds.

Comment: How can I include YYYY-MM-DD? I already got over 8,000 rows of Time without date.  So 23:30 would be 2011-05-18 23:30:30 and 00:00 is 2011-05-19 00:00:00 ?

Comment: @user622378: How is your code supposed to guess which day the time is from? Or do you intend to use "now" as the pivot point?

Comment: Example: $nowTime = HourMinuteToDecimal(date('H:i')); $OpenTime = HourMinuteToDecimal($data['Result'][$key]['opentime']);   if ($nowTime > $OpenTime) { .. } It work but not when the time over 00:00

Comment: @user622378: That does not answer my question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, how would this work if the date doesn't matter? Or if the date always needs to be the current date? For example, my company opens every day at 8:00:00 and closes at 20:00:00. If the time is before 8:00:00 or after 20:00:00, I want to hide a certain link (live text chat link). I guess we can try storing the current date from date() in a variable and concatenating it with the time to get something with a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format....

Comment: @KennyJohnson: That one's easy -- you're not trying to compare anything, merely choosing a range. You can split that range in two - 00:00:00->08:00:00 and 20:00:00->23:59:59. Without a date, you can trivially pick up times within those ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare objects of type `time` using the standard `<`, `>`, `==` operators. Use `strtotime` to convert the string to time, then compare.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by objects of type time. The times are stored in the database using 'time' field type. 17:00:00, 178:00:00, 00:00:00, 01:00:00, etc

Comment: When you load time values from the database, they will be strings. Use `strtotime` to convert those strings to times.

Comment: I don't think we should bring UNIX timestamps into it. We are not dealing with dates.