# add time in format h:i:s

Tags: php

I have array like below:

```
array
(
    [0] => 505:25:32
    [1] => 480:00:01
    [2] => 504:00:01
    [3] => 480:00:02
)
```

I want to add it and get total time in `h:i:s`. I have thought of split this array into three

```
hour_array(
        [0] => 505
        [1] => 480
        [2] => 504
        [3] => 480
)
min_array(
        [0] => 25
        [1] => 00
        [2] => 00
        [3] => 00
)
sec_array(
        [0] =>32
        [1] => 01
        [2] => 01
        [3] => 02
)
```

then add each array individually and do sum of them later.
but this solution seems bit lengthy its there another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$original_array = array
(
        '505:25:32',
        '480:00:01',
        '504:00:01',
        '480:00:02'
);

$hours=0;
$minutes=0;
$seconds=0;
foreach($original_array AS $value){
    $chunks= explode(":", $value);
    $hours += $chunks[0];
    $minutes += $chunks[1];
    $seconds += $chunks[2];
}

$minutes += floor($seconds / 60);
$seconds %= 60;

$hours += floor($minutes /60);
$minutes %= 60;

var_dump(get_defined_vars());
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to parse the strings anyway, then you can just add to the totals, like so:

```
$totalHours = 0;
$totalMinutes = 0;
$totalSeconds = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($times); $i++)
{
   $parsedTime = FunctionToParseStringIntoTime($times[$i]);
   $totalHours += $parsedTime['hours'];
   $totalMinutes += $parsedTime['minutes'];
   $totalSeconds += $parsedTime['seconds'];
}
```

I've been using the function from here recently, [Convert time to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047693/convert-time-to-seconds)

That will get you the total minutes. To make it give an associative array, I would do something like so:

```
function FunctionToParseStringIntoTime($theTime) 
 {
    $t = explode(':', $theTime);
    return array("hours" => intval($t[0]), "minutes" => intval($t[1]), "seconds" => intval($t[2]));
 }
```

Comment: but in this minutes and seconds can come above 60 minutes and 60 seconds so i have to add it in hrs and sec accordindly

Answer (score 0):

foreach in your original array

```
$hours= array();
$min= array();
$sec= array();
foreach($original_array AS $key=> $value){
  $chunk= explode(":", $value);
  $hour[$key]= $chunk[0];
  $min[$key]= $chunk[1];
  $sec[$key]= $chunk[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using multi-dimensional array.

That should make your work easy and code more readable.

You could add the ":" only on display.